# Bind start of a Path to an animating View in Android

Tags: android, animation

I would like to create an effect in my application running on Android 4.4 where I have an `ImageView` that I am simply animating it X/Y position on the screen using the Property Animation approach via the `View.animate()` methods.

This all works fine, but I would like to enhance my current scene by drawing a Path from the location of my `ImageView` **as it animates** across and around my screen (complex Path with lots of bends), I am really not sure how to do this properly.

My idea so far is to create a subclass of a `View` that will draw the Path via `onDraw()`, and have a `Path` field on this class that changes on each tick of the animation, but I dont know if this is the correct approach, or how to actually hook into each frame of the animation (is this what the `Animator.AnimatorListener` is for?)

Can someone please guide me on this?